# City east or west coast US

Tags: latitude-longitude

How can I find whether a city in US belongs to east or west coast by using its latitude and longitude?

I have the lat and long for the city in US but could not find if it belongs to east or west

Comment: This problem is poorly specified and makes significant faulty assumptions about the basics of US geography. Do you consider an inland city of a coastal state as East/West coast? What about Seattle (it's along Puget Sound but east of the Olympic Mountains)? What about a city such as St. Louis? If you don't know, define the problem further. If it's not relevant, find a geometric line (e.g. 100 deg West) that divides your two "coasts" and just check if the city falls to the east/west of that line.

Comment: The US has more territory than the two coasts. Where do you think Dallas, Dubuque, Chicago, Detroit, and Kansas City are? There is no East or West coast near any of them. To answer your question, you need to define where you consider the East and West coast boundaries are, and then you can see if your lat and long are east or west of those boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a map showing latitudes. Decide where you want to cutover.

https://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/countrys/usalats.htm

Maybe `> 115` could be west coast, `< 95` east coast?

Comment: I didn't downvote this because it contains the right idea given what the OP has provided--that said, I would add a note to be careful with the signs as there's a chance that the western hemisphere would be represented numerically with a negative longitude. Right off the bat, I see that Google Maps appears to use this convention--all points in the western hemisphere have a negative longitude (both on the website and on the API).